How to use swift macros in a development pod
I want to use my own swift macro in a pod for my main project. When I use the macro in my development pod I get the error 'External macro implementation type XXX could not be found for macro XXX'.
The swift macro I created is built using SPM and the file path of its compiled binary has already been placed correctly in '-load-plugin-library' and I can use my macro perfectly in the main project, but what I truly want is using it in one of my development pods. It seems the binary is visible only to the main project, not to the pod, so I can import my macro-wrapping pod in my pod, but when I use the macro, I get the error I mentioned above. What can I do to make it right or this will be a dead end?
